# How can I do a setOnClickListener to a fragment that is not in my Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 3 fragments here I show them, they have a TextView with the id omitir_swipe, and I need to use it in the activity where I show those 3 fragments, how would I achieve it?:

3 fragments xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_swipe"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/books_swipe"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.246"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.329"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
        android:text="Amantium irae amoris integratio est."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image_swipe"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/image_swipe"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.465"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_swipe" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/omitir_swipe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Omitir"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The 3 are the same so I only upload 1, they have the same id, to only use 1, I don't know if this is good, could you tell me whether to change it or not

3 Fragments .kt kotlin:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.yr.iolite.R

class SwipeFragement1 : Fragment()
{
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_screen_1, container, false)
    }
}
```

in the 3 only change this number fragment_splash_screen_*change this number*

The activity where I show the 3 fragments xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Splash.SplashActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg_snow_splash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_snow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_splash"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/penguin_splash"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.391"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo_splash"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/party_penguin"
        />

    <com.cuberto.liquid_swipe.LiquidPager
        android:id="@+id/swipe_screen"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The .kt from the previous activity:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
import com.yr.iolite.MainActivity
import com.yr.iolite.R
import com.yr.iolite.WriteProblem.MinOrMax
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_splash.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_splash_screen_1.*

class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    var bg: ImageView? = null
    var logo: ImageView? = null
    var penguin: LottieAnimationView? = null
    var anim: Animation? = null
    private var pagerAdapter : ScreenSliderPagerAdapter? = null
    private val SPLASH_TIME_OUT : Int = 5500
    private var sharedPref : SharedPreferences ? = null
    private var omitir_swipe : TextView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        bg = findViewById(R.id.bg_snow_splash)
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo_splash)
        penguin = findViewById(R.id.penguin_splash)
        omitir_swipe = findViewById(R.id.omiti_swipe)

        val viewPager : ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.swipe_screen)
        pagerAdapter = ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.swipe_screen_anim)
        viewPager.startAnimation(anim)
        bg_snow_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(-1600f)
        }
        logo_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(-1400f)
        }
        penguin_splash.animate().apply {
            duration = 1000
            startDelay = 4000
            translationY(1400f)
        }

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            var sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE)
            var isFirstTime : Boolean = sharedPref.getBoolean("firstTime", true)
            if(isFirstTime)
            {
                var editor : SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
                editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false)
                editor.commit()
            }
            else
            {
                val intent = Intent(this, MinOrMax::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Intento con exito")
                }
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }, 5000)

        /*findViewById<TextView>(R.id.omitir_swipe).setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "xd")
            }
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }*/
    }
    private class ScreenSliderPagerAdapter (fm : FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm)
    {
        val NUM_TABS = 3
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment
        {
            return when (position)
            {
                0 -> SwipeFragement1()
                1 -> SwipeFragement2()
                else -> SwipeFragement3()
            }
        }
        override fun getCount(): Int = NUM_TABS
    }
}
```

I don't have any errors but when I uncomment the setOnClickListener it doesn't work it gives me a null pointer exception error, and that is because the id of the omit_swipe is not in the activity xml as you can see above instead it is in the fragments.

Comment: You can't access the frament's views in activity.  Set clickListener in fragment itself.

Comment: @iamanbansal So how do the splash activities do?

Comment: do what? what do you want to do?

Comment: @iamanbansal How do applications with welcome fragments that slide and that at the end you have to press the skip button and it just goes to the mainActivity?

Comment: You can call the startactivity from fragment and finish as well

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new activity and finish the current from the fragment.

```
class SwipeFragement1 : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_screen_1, container, false)
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.omitir_swipe).setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "xd")
            }
            activity.startActivity(intent)
            activity.finish()
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems very good to me, but how would I do the part of the ***Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed***  as this helps me so that this activity is not shown again

Comment: And where would the return be?